# how to write and display a webservice from asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, xml

This method reads a file into an asp table, then when button is pressed the fields in the textboxes add a new element to the tablerow. There seems to be something broken and I don't know how to fix it.

```
namespace ReadPeople
{
    public partial class ReadAndWrite : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<People> people = new ReadXml().ReadXmlDoc();
            for(int i=0; i<people.Count; ++i)
            {
                People person = people[i];
            TableRow tr = new TableRow();
            TableCell tcName = new TableCell();
            TableCell tcBirthdate = new TableCell();

            tcName.Text = person.fName + " " + person.lName;
            tcBirthdate.Text = person.month;

            tr.Cells.Add(tcName);
            tr.Cells.Add(tcBirthdate);
            tableAll.Rows.Add(tr);
        }
    }

    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        People person = new People();
        person.fName = txtFName.Text;
        person.lName = txtLName.Text;
        person.month = txtMonth.Text;
        WriteXml write = new WriteXml();

        write.WriteToXmlDoc(person);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: We can help but we need more details. What exactly does not work? Does it throw an exception? Is it working but not how you want?

Comment: Your problem, (by guessing the problem is, inserted person is not listed on the page in the table) is, Page_Load is invoked BEFORE the btnAdd_Click event handler. Therefore, you get the list of poeple FIRST, and add the new person LATER.